# Need help understanding how LazyCollection works in this scenario

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This project has 3 models:

- `Concert`: has many Tickets, belongs to many Orders.
- `Ticket`: id, concert_id (not nullable), order_id (nullable)
- `Order`: *not really relevant, but added for completion*

I've been playing around with LazyCollections, but I don't fully understand how they work. I ran into some trouble implementing a `reserveTickets` method for my `Concert` class. I can easily fix it by using a normal `Collection` instead of a `LazyCollection` but I want to understand **why** this is happening.

```php
// Create 1 Concert
$concert = Concert::factory()->create();
// Create 3 tickets associated to the concert.
Ticket::factory()->for($concert)->count(3)->create();
// Reserve 2 tickets (set their reserved_at timestamp) and return them
$reservedTickets = $concert->reserveTickets(quantity: 2);

// Does not contain the 2 reserved tickets I expect it should have.
$reservedTickets->all();
```

The `reserveTickets` method depends on the `findTickets` method. Both are defined in the `Concert` model.

```php
public function reserveTickets(int $quantity): LazyCollection
{
    return $this->findTickets($quantity)->each->reserve();
}

public function findTickets(int $quantity): LazyCollection
{
    $tickets = $this->tickets()->available()->limit($quantity)->cursor();

    throw_if(exception: NotEnoughTicketsException::class, condition: $quantity > $tickets->count());

    return $tickets;
}
```

If I change `findTickets`'s implementation to

```php
$tickets = $this->tickets()->available()->limit($quantity)->cursor()->remember();
```

<s>The custom `NotEnoughTicketsException` will be thrown when accessing the contents of the `LazyCollection`</s> It actually works. I don't understand why it failed before.

Not using `remember()` makes the SELECT query execute 3 times, making the `throw_if` line useless most of the time.

---

---

Here is the relevant code for the models.

`Concert` model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Exceptions\NotEnoughTicketsException;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Support\{Collection, LazyCollection};

class Concert extends Eloquent\Model
{
    use Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    /* RELATIONSHIPS */
    public function tickets(): Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
    }

    public function orders(): Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class, 'tickets');
    }

    /* METHODS */
    public function orderTickets(string $email, int $ticket_quantity): Order
    {
        $tickets = $this->findTickets($ticket_quantity);

        return $this->createOrder($email, $tickets);
    }

    public function reserveTickets(int $quantity): LazyCollection
    {
        return $this->findTickets($quantity)->each->reserve();
    }

    public function findTickets(int $quantity): LazyCollection
    {
        $tickets = $this->tickets()->available()->limit($quantity)->cursor();

        throw_if(exception: NotEnoughTicketsException::class, condition: $quantity > $tickets->count());

        return $tickets;
    }
}
```

`Ticket` model

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent;

class Ticket extends Eloquent\Model
{
    use Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    /* SCOPES */
    public function scopeAvailable(Eloquent\Builder $query): void
    {
        $query->whereNull('order_id')->whereNull('reserved_at');
    }

    /* METHODS */
    public function reserve(): void
    {
        $this->fill(['reserved_at' => now()])->save();
    }
}
```

[image: Tinker session showing described behavior]

Comment: How do you check the collection to see, it does not return the two as expected?

Comment: By dumping `$reservedTickets->all();`

Comment: I believe i can explain the case without using remember(), that version will fetch each ticket call, therefor after you updated em, they are reserved therefor not available when you call the all() method. Why remember does not give the correct result, i can't seem to figure out as of now.

Comment: So basically, not using `remember()`, the query is executing... 3 times instead of once. I have no idea why remember was failing _before_, but now it seems to be working as intended.